# Combining arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays of objects. How can I combine/concat them in to one array of object.

I have tried using the concat function as well iterating through arr2 and pushing them in arr1, but I want to do in a shorter way instead.

```
let arr1 = [{
  _id: 1,
  external_id: '74341f74-9c79-49d5-9611-87ef9b6eb75f',
  name: 'Francisca Rasmussen',
  alias: 'Miss Coffey'
 },
  { _id: 19,
    external_id: '68e35e26-7b1f-46ec-a9e5-3edcbcf2aeb9',
    name: 'Francis Rodrigüez',
    alias: 'Mr Lea'
  },
  { _id: 23,
    external_id: 'e9db9277-af4a-4ca6-99e0-291c8a97623e',
    name: 'Francis Bailey',
    alias: 'Miss Singleton'
  }];

let arr2 =   [ { organizations: 'Multron', joining_key: 1 },
  { organizations: 'Bitrex', joining_key: 19 },
  { organizations: 'Enthaze', joining_key: 23 },
  { tickets: 'A Nuisance in Kiribati', joining_key: 1 },
  { tickets: 'A Nuisance in Saint Lucia', joining_key: 19 }
  { tickets: 'A Nuisance in Saint Kilda', joining_key: 19 }
  ]
```

I want to concat them which gives result as below based on the joining_key which is _id field on arr1:

```
   [{
  _id: 1,
  external_id: '74341f74-9c79-49d5-9611-87ef9b6eb75f',
  name: 'Francisca Rasmussen',
  alias: 'Miss Coffey',
  organizations: 'Multron',
  tickets: 'A Nuisance in Kiribati', joining_key: 1
},
  { _id: 19,
    external_id: '68e35e26-7b1f-46ec-a9e5-3edcbcf2aeb9',
    name: 'Francis Rodrigüez',
    alias: 'Mr Lea',
    organizations: 'Bitrex',
    tickets: 'A Nuisance in Saint Lucia',
    tickets: 'A Nuisance in Saint Kilda'
  },
  { _id: 23,
    external_id: 'e9db9277-af4a-4ca6-99e0-291c8a97623e',
    name: 'Francis Bailey',
    alias: 'Miss Singleton',
    organizations: 'Enthaze'
  }]
```

Comment: What happens if the arrays contain additional objects?

Comment: It's very unclear why `arr1` is an array and not a single object and what should happen if the array has another object.

Comment: @Amy If arr2 contains any additional objects they are all combined to arr1. Eg : If arr2 contains tickets_3, the result will have ticket_3 as well in the resulting object

Comment: We're more concerned about what happens if  `arr1` has more than one item @MollyChristian

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking.  Both of your arrays contain one object.  Will they always contain one object, and if not, how are the arrays combined?

Comment: @amy `arr2` has several objects.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Ah, i see that now.  I was mentally combining them.

Comment: @shadoe2020 The OP is not trying to concatenate two arrays.  Your answer was incorrect.

Comment: @Amy Modified my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign(...arr1)` for this case

More reference for Spread Operator at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```js
let arr1 = [{ _id: 1,
    external_id: '74341f74-9c79-49d5-9611-87ef9b6eb75f',
    name: 'Francisca Rasmussen',
    alias: 'Miss Coffey',
    created_at: '2016-04-15T05:19:46 -10:00'
}];

let arr2 = [ { organizations: 'Multron' },
  { tickets_1: 'A Nuisance in Kiribati' },
  { tickets_2: 'A Nuisance in Saint Lucia' }
  ];
  
  
  arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2)
  //console.log(arr1)
  let result = [Object.assign(...arr1)]
  console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the edits, it's a much different question. Your array has `_id` properties which you want to use to lookup the items. `arr1` should probably be an object, which would make it possible to find a particular item given an id without searching the whole list . In fact, it's probably best to make a lookup object you can use to merge the objects (although you could use `find()` on the array.

Then just step through the `arr2` and add the objects to the correct item from `arr1`:

```js
let arr1 = [{_id: 1,external_id: '74341f74-9c79-49d5-9611-87ef9b6eb75f',name: 'Francisca Rasmussen',alias: 'Miss Coffey'},{ _id: 19,external_id: '68e35e26-7b1f-46ec-a9e5-3edcbcf2aeb9',name: 'Francis Rodrigüez',alias: 'Mr Lea'},{ _id: 23,external_id: 'e9db9277-af4a-4ca6-99e0-291c8a97623e',name: 'Francis Bailey',alias: 'Miss Singleton'}];
let arr2 = [ { organizations: 'Multron', joining_key: 1 },{ organizations: 'Bitrex', joining_key: 19 },{ organizations: 'Enthaze', joining_key: 23 },{ tickets: 'A Nuisance in Kiribati', joining_key: 1 },{ tickets: 'A Nuisance in Saint Lucia', joining_key: 19 },{ tickets: 'A Nuisance in Saint Kilda', joining_key: 19 }]

// make lookup 
let lookup = arr1.reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item._id] = item, obj), {})

// merge objects using lookup
arr2.forEach(item => {
  let {joining_key, ...rest} = item        // seperate join_key-it's not in the final result 
  Object.assign(lookup[joining_key], rest)
})

// arr1 now has merged objects
console.log(console.log(arr1))
```

Note: your desired result gives the object with `_id: 19` two `tickets` properties. Properties must be unique on objects, so this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the spread operator

```
const arr3 = [{ ...arr1[0], ...arr2[0] }]
```

Quite straightforward, isn't it?

In your case, this would return an array with a single object (the two objects are now combined)

Answer (score 0):

Push the arrays into another array [Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

```
//array1 with some content
let array1=["item1","item2"];
//array2 with some content
let array2=["item3","item4"];
//create empty array
let array3=[];
//concatenate arrays
//add array1
array3.push(array1);
//add array2
array3.push(array2);
//display result
console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will give you answers i don't know if its best solution but it worked on me.

```
arr1.forEach(element => {
  var filtered = arr2.filter(obj => obj.joining_key === element._id);
  filtered.forEach(filtered_object => {
    let i = 0;
    Object.keys(filtered_object).forEach(key => {
      if (i == 0) {
        element[key] = filtered_object[key]
      }
      i = i + 1;
    })
  })
})
```